# Shortening the URL Routing

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

This is my sample:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("template1", "{name}/template1", "~/area/template1.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("template2", "{name}/template2", "~/area/template2.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("template3", "{name}/template3", "~/area/template3.aspx")
...
routes.MapPageRoute("templateN", "{name}/templateN", "~/area/templateN.aspx")
```

Whenever I add a new template, I need to add a new MapPageRoute line into my global file.

Is there a way to shorten it so it could represent everything? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put all the names such as `template1`, `template2`, ... into an array and loop over that?

Basically, something like:

```
var routes = new [ 'template1', 'template2', 'template3' ];

foreach (var route in routes)
{
    routesMapPageRoute(route, "{name}/" + route, "~/area/" + route + ".aspx");
}
```